# How many pt's is 1,5 line spacing in Microsoft Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, line-spacing

Sometimes I need to manually enter pt's and I want it look the same as 1,5 line spacing. How many pt's is it?

Comment: Doesn't this sort of depend on the font? One single line would likely be the height of the font in points and depends on the font, whereas points is an arbitrary measure of 72 points to the inch (1 point = 1⁄72 inches = 25.4⁄72 mm = 0.3527 mm)

Comment: @camster342 argh I made mistake i meant 1.5 line spacing, or it's also depend on font?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As camster said, it is impossible to give you an answer as it is directly dependent on the font and size of the font you are using.

If you need to enter one and a half lines of space, consider using maths - e.g. if your font is 20, enter a new line and set it to 30, then another line of normal!

(p.s. you may want to check(and disable) normal line spacing as you will have a gap above and below the new/blank line).

Answer (score 3):

The amount of leading varies depending on which font you are using (not all 12-point fonts are equal). Typically, single-spaced lines range from 110% to 135% of the font size. For example, let’s say you select Times New Roman, a font that is common in legal documents. If you set the font size at 12 points and apply single spacing, the true height of your lines of text will be roughly 115% to 120% of the point size, or 13.8 to 14.4 points.

see this link
http://compusavvy.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/understanding-line-and-paragraph-spacing-in-word/